# No stepper motor movement on Ender 3 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware

I've recently updated my Ender 3 Pro to the latest Marlin 2.0 firmware and when I press autohome or try to move the axis, I hear a very quiet noise from the motors trying to move and then they just don't. I did get an error message about EEPROM when I first booted the printer after flashing but I just pressed reset and the issue hasn't come back even after trying multiple different firmware versions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! This could we'll be related to an incorrectly configured configuration file, it is very hard to guess what is causing this with this little information.

Comment: Jacob, were you able to resolve your issue with steppers movement? If my response below helped you (and you can accept it to close question)? Or do you have any other explanation to share, like stepper driver settings in firmware? I am very curious of the actual reason. Also let us know if you still struggle with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theoretical assumption, but I suppose that your steps/mm values are now wrong in the EEPROM - specifically that they are set to 0 (**zeroed steps per mm**)? Could you please use the LCD and navigate to *Configuration > Advanced Settings > Steps per mm* and check what values are set there? If there are zeros, could you set them to positive values (e.g. =80) and check homing again? Then save the changes using *Configuration > Store Settings*.

I just made the following test proving that this may be the cause. I set steps per mm for X=0 (executed G-Code: `M92 X0` from serial terminal) and tried to move X. The stepper motor was enabled (quiet noise or hiss), but it didn't move at all. There was no additional feedback e.g. on LCD. Pretty similar.

If this is not the only broken setting, then option *Configuration > Restore Defaults* should reset the EEPROM to values defined in Marlin's configuration. I needed to perform *Configuration > Store Settings* to make it persistent. But this will reset many other values, so I would suggest writing down all current values from LCD before doing the reset, for reference in future (in case they were valuable). And you still may not see all of the settings on the LCD, therefore I would use G-code for this operation - see below.

These operations can be also performed from a serial terminal using G-Code commands: [M503](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M503.html) to verify and copy the current configuration, and [M502](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M502.html) followed by [M500](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M500.html) to perform a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

In your platformio.ini file check the `default_envs` variable if it's `mega2560` set it to your board type, [this](https://youtu.be/S0epn4ANJlo?t=187) video from ruiraptor explains how to get your board type. It fixed it for my Ender 3.